# GWT Browser Refresh

Tags: gwt, refresh

If I Implement below mentioned code in my application.

```
 Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() { 
    @Override 
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) { 
        event.setMessage("Are you sure ?"); 
        }}); 
        Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) 
            {} 
        });
```

User is presented with a Confirmation dialog and If he says "stay on 
this page" , then Nothing happens.

I would like to know which code can be written to have the same 
behaviour without having need of any confirmation dialog.

Is there any JSNI OR any way by which we can have the same behaviour 
achived wihtout any dialog

Comment: Do you stopping user from closing window/tab without his confirmation?! I doubt that you can!

Comment: I agree but if something which is already available in GWT , can't we overwrite the same with our behaviour.

Comment: It has been made available by browser and GWT just provide an interface to it. You can use it in plain JS too.

Comment: By the way my first comment should be: Do you mean stopping...

Comment: What JS code I need to write ? Can you please provide me the sample code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is "nothing happens"? You just keep looking at the blank page or?

Comment: Means I stay on the same page.